# Unable to bind data using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am unable to get binding to work.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
When I attempt to display the value of the header on the page, the page generated is "{{name}}" instead of "My App".

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="appModule">
<head ng-controller="appController">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Home</title>

    <script src="~/Views/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        /// <reference path="~/Views/Scripts/angular.js" />

        var appModule = angular.module("appModule", []);

        appModule.controller("appController", function ($scope)
        {
            $scope.name = "My App";
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should avoid using a tilde in your URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by loading angular directly from google CDN, so the error might be in the loading of angular

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9JyX6/

```
<html ng-app="appModule">
<head ng-controller="appController">
    <title>Home</title>

    <script>
        /// <reference path="~/Views/Scripts/angular.js" />

        var appModule = angular.module("appModule", []);

        appModule.controller("appController", function ($scope)
        {
            $scope.name = "My App";
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated script tag syntax using "../":  <script src="../Views/Scripts/angular.js"></script>